# Fatal Error in MPI_Wait

Tags: c++, mpi

Here is the output for a source code implementation shown below. I am not sure what it means and how i should remedy the code.

```
 aborting job:
 Fatal error in MPI_Wait: Invalid MPI_Request, error stack:
 MPI_Wait(139): MPI_Wait(request=0xffffd6a4, status0xffffd690) failed
 MPI_Wait(75) : Invalid MPI_Request
 rank 0 in job 1 <processor #) caused collective abort of all ranks
 exit status of rank 0: return code 13
```

SOURCE CODE:

```
 #define Rows 48 
 ...

  double *northedge1 = new double[Rows];
  double *northofnorthedge3 = new double[Rows];
  ...
  ...

  int main (int argc, char *argv[])
  {
  ....
  ....

  MPI_Request send_request, recv_request;
  ...
  ...


  if ((my_rank) == 1)
  {
  MPI_Isend(northedge1, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_request); 
  }

  if ((my_rank) == 3)
  {
  MPI_Irecv(northofnorthedge3, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank-2, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD,   
  &send_request);
  }


  MPI_Wait(&send_request, &status);
  .....
  MPI_Finalize ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're calling the MPI_Wait() even from rank 0, even though you're only doing nonblocking communications in rank 1 and 3.   So there's no valid send_request in rank 0, so the MPI_Wait is invalid.   In the above, it looks like you should have

```
 if ( (my_rank == 1) || (my_rank == 3))   
      MPI_Wait(&send_request, &status);
```

Comment: Jonathan: Thanks. I fixed this but I noticed that when I do multiple MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv within one "if" statement with an MPI_Wait, only the very last MPI_Irecv, seems to execute OK.  My question is, do I have to take a look at the order of Send/Recv commands or should each MPI_Recv should be followed by an MPI_Wait command? thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can't keep recieving (or sending, or both) into the same Request; a request is a like a tracking number for the pending communications, you don't want to overwrite any.  If you're going to have several pending requests, you're best off having several MPI_Requests and statuses in an array (eg, `MPI_Request reqs[5]; MPI_Status stats[5];`) and then using them one at a time (`MPI_Isend(...,reqs[0]); MPI_Irecv(...,reqs[1]); ...`) and then using an `MPI_Waitall(5,reqs,stats)`) to wait for all of them.  There's a Wait_any if you want to loop through and process them one at a time, too.

Comment: Jonathan: I tried what you had suggested and have included the link to the query. I was unable to post the excerpt of the code here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052486/non-blocking-communication-in-mpi-and-mpi-wait-issue-not-all-information-is-pass>. I noticed that not all of the information I wish is getting passed through. I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't overlooking somthing in the syntax or the way the code was setup. your input will be much appreciated. Thanks!