# MPI_Isend/Recv- Is there a deadlock?

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a total of 8 messages being passed on 4 nodes using MPI. I noticed that there were two messages whose arrays did not provide meaningful results. I have copied an excerpt of the code below? These are some related questions I had based on the code/results below:

1. Does the MPI_Isend also require a wait? I am not sure if there is a deadlock. I also tried just passing these two variables from one node to the other, and the array values were still NULL.
2. Will MPI_SendRecv improve the efficiency of the code as suggested here [Non Blocking communication in MPI and MPI Wait Issue. Not all information is passed correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052486/non-blocking-communication-in-mpi-and-mpi-wait-issue-not-all-information-is-pass)? If so, how/why? Would also appreciate some pointers on setting that up.

Thanks!

```
Source Code:

if ((my_rank) == 0)
{
MPI_Irecv(A, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+1, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[6]);
MPI_Wait(&request[6], &status[6]);
}


if ((my_rank) == 1)
{
MPI_Isend(AA, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[6]);
}


if ((my_rank) == 2)
{
MPI_Isend(B, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[7]);
}

if ((my_rank) == 3)
{
MPI_Irecv(BB, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank-1, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[7]);
MPI_Wait(&request[7], &status[7]);
}
```

Comment: There isn't nearly enough context here to figure out what is going on.  What is B, BB, A, AA, Rows?   What variables don't have sensible values here?  What do you mean that the array values are NULL?    A complete code segment which demonstrates the problem is best.    As to your other questions, yes, both Isend and Irecv's should be matched to wait or similar, and No, in this particular case a sendrecv doesn't match the pattern given (in the above case, no one task is both sending and receiving).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I was able to fix the bug. It has to do with how I was printing than the Send/recv. commands. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, All non-blocking calls (MPI_Isend, MPI_Irecv etc) require a matching MPI_Wait. The call is not guaranteed to complete until MPI_Wait is called. You should not change the contents of the buffer until after MPI_Wait returns.

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/

To use SendRecv, same task has to send a message and wait to receive a message. That pattern doesnt hold true for your code.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on " Contents of buffer must not change until after MPI_Wait returns?". Since, MPI_Isend/recv are non blocking commands, which means, computing occurs simultaneously as communication does, so wouldn't that imply that the buffer is being updated on the fly? I am not quite clear on that. Would appreciate if you did clarify. Thanks!

Comment: SOrry for the late response. The non-blocking call only guarantees that it will return the function ASAP. It does not guarantee that the data was actually sent/received. Thats the important distinction. Since the call just returned and not guaranteed to be completed on return, we cannot reuse the buffer. Think of it as .. the function just started a background thread and returned. the thread is doing the work of send/recv. To guarantee the work was completed, you should call MPI_Wait. It will block till the function actually did the work and completed.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using a blocking send/recv. In terms of efficiency/timing, is non blocking better than blocking send/recv?

Comment: The main advantage of non-blocking is that you need not wait on the communication call to finish. You can overlap the communication with the computation and increase your efficiency. But if you have no work to be done during communication, the CPU just idles in MPI_Wait. So it depends on your algo / program structure to utilize the provided mechanism to improve your efficiency. Just blindly using non-blocking will be no different than blocking.

Comment: Thank you! Your response was very useful.